# Optional argument for path and deep linking

Tags: javascript, react-navigation, deep-linking

I have a stack navigator for which I want a deep linking path. For this path, I can have an optional argument (`param2`), but what I've seen online doesn't work (putting the optional arguments in parenthesis):

```
 ex: {
        screen: Screen,
      },
    path: "ex/:param1(/:param2)",
  },
```

The default behavior works if I use either `ex/:param1` or `ex/:param1/:param2`, meaning the deep linking is set up properly and a standard path works. The thing is, the optional part doesn't (tried the old `paths` as well to no avail).

The code itself seems to indicate that there is a way of having this kind of behavior (with the regex), but can't find anything in the documentation on something that does seem like a "standard" use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A year late, and possibly a version or two off, but the `?` syntax works for this:

```
path: "ex/:param1/:param2?"
```